# How to copy table from SAP GUI to one sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I have a `GuiGridView` object in SAP GUI as shown in below picture.
I can use function download in SAP GUI to Excel by VBA SAP GUI script, but slowly.

I want to copy directly data from the SAP GUI window to a sheet of an Excel file, via the actions Select all rows, Copy and Paste, but the SAP GUI Scripting Recorder does not record these actions.

Please help me write this code.

[image]

```
Sub Test()

    Windows("Mod-Telit.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Put away").Select
    If Not IsObject(sApplication) Then
        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        Set sApplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
       Set Connection = sApplication.Children(0)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(session) Then
       Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If
    If IsObject(WScript) Then
       WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
       WScript.ConnectObject sApplication, "on"
    End If
    
    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/ncoois"   ' T-code Coois
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_TOPBLOCK:PPIO_ENTRY:1100/cmbPPIO_ENTRY_SC1100-PPIO_LISTTYP").Key = "PPIOM000"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_TOPBLOCK:PPIO_ENTRY:1100/ctxtPPIO_ENTRY_SC1100-ALV_VARIANT").Text = "/V1517171"  ' Select layout
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_SELBLOCK/tabpSEL_00/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_SELBLOCK:PPIO_ENTRY:1200/ctxtS_AUFNR-LOW").Text = Workbooks("Mod-Telit.xlsm").Sheets("Put away").Range("B3") ' PON number in excel
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_SELBLOCK/tabpSEL_00/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_SELBLOCK:PPIO_ENTRY:1200/ctxtS_AUFNR-LOW").SetFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
    
    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID_0100/shellcont/shell").setCurrentCell -1, ""
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID_0100/shellcont/shell").SelectAll

    ***' Next is code copy*** ????????

    Windows("Mod-Telit.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I used to replace the Copy/Paste process.

```
Set myGrid = session.findbyID("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")
allRows = myGrid.RowCount - 1 'number of SAP rows
allCols = myGrid.ColumnCount - 1 'number of SAP Columns
Dim columns As Object
Set columns = myGrid.ColumnOrder 'SAP column names in order in SAP window


 For j = 0 To allRows
 myGrid.firstVisibleRow = j
  For i = 0 To allCols
   ActiveSheet.Cells(j + 1, i + 1).Value = myGrid.GetCellValue(j, columns(i)) 'starts in cell "A1"
  Next i
 Next j
```

Slows down with lots of data but gets the job done. Could try setting the info to an Array first my speed up the code a bit but its the transfer from SAP that slows down with more data.