# How to copy a value from SAP GUI Grid View and paste to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

With the transaction code `ZRQ_RTG_TOOL_QRY` in SAP system, I'm attempting to directly copy and paste a data row for every iteration of whatever vendor it is that I'm running. The SAP GUI script recorder does not record the action of selecting Copy Text within the context menu when right clicking on the data row. So that's where is throwing the error in the below code.

Is this just a limit of the SAP script recorder functionality?

Code:

```
Sub SupplierScorecard()

    '--------------------------------------------------------
    'Connecting to SAP:                                     '
    Dim SAPGUIAuto     As Object                            '
    Dim SAPApplication As Object                            '
    Dim Connection     As Object                            '
    Dim session        As Object                            '
                                                            '
        Set SAPGUIAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")                '
        Set SAPApplication = SAPGUIAuto.GetScriptingEngine  '
        Set Connection = SAPApplication.Children(0)         '
        Set session = Connection.Children(0)                '
    '--------------------------------------------------------
    
    '--------------------------------------------------------
    'Define Variables                                       '
    Dim WB As Workbook                                      '
    Dim WS As Worksheet                                '
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long
                                                            '
                                                            '
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set WS = WB.Worksheets("MFC Data Extract")    '
                                                            '
    LR = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                                                            '
    '--------------------------------------------------------
    
    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "ZRQ_RTG_TOOL_QRY"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_RCOMP-LOW").Text = "MFC"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_EFFDT").Text = "08/31/2021"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_DOC_DF").Text = ".5"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_SUP_DF").Text = ".5"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_SRC_DF").Text = "1"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_RIN_DF").Text = "1"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_MFG_DF").Text = "2"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_PI_DF").Text = "2"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_1_VF").Text = "1"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_2_VF").Text = "1"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_3_VF").Text = "1"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_4_VF").Text = "1"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_5_VF").Text = "1"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_6_VF").Text = "1"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_7_VF").Text = "1"
    
    For i = 2 To LR
    
    VendorID = WS.Cells(i, "B").Value
    
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_LIFNR").Text = VendorID
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_LIFNR").caretPosition = 9
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
        session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectedRows = "0"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").currentCellColumn = "RPT_GRP_LVL"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").doubleClickCurrentCell
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").contextMenu
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItemByPosition "0" *ERROR HERE SAYING INVALID ARGUMENT
         
            Range(i, "S").PasteSpecial
            
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
        
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The whole row or only one cell? My comment focuses for one cell and you can adapt to do it for multiple cells: you don't need to copy and paste, you can just get the Grid cell value programatically (method `GetCellValue`), into a variable, and initialize the Excel cell with the variable. Example: `value=grid.GetCellValue(gridrow,"RPT_GRP_LVL"):Range(i, "S").Value2=value`

Comment: The SAP GUI recorder doesn't create VBScript code for the actions related to Windows, like the clipboard. You must code yourself this part. You can search `SendKeys` in the Web to simulate Ctrl+C keys.

Comment: Please fix the indentation to make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't Copy and Paste, instead just set the Excel file cells equal to the grid values
[How to copy table from SAP GUI to one sheet in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67392863/how-to-copy-table-from-sap-gui-to-one-sheet-in-excel)